# "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'" when building a Windows Forms project

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a rock-paper-scissors minigame in Visual Studio but I got the message:

> `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'`

Please help, I would really appreciate it, since I am not an expert at Visual Studio. I have tried converting every way around but could not find a solution...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class ablak3 : Form
    {
        static int computer = 0;

        public ablak3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ablak3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
            pictureBox4.Visible = false;
            pictureBox5.Visible = false;
            pictureBox6.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
            pictureBox4.Visible = false;
            pictureBox5.Visible = false;
            pictureBox6.Visible = false;

            var random = new Random();
            computer = random.Next(1,4);            

            if (computer = 1)
                pictureBox1.Visible = true;
                label8.Text = "Tie!";                               
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo.  You're using the assignment operator (`=`) where you meant to use a comparison operator (`==`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this operator (==) instead of this (=).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        pictureBox3.Visible = false;
        pictureBox4.Visible = false;
        pictureBox5.Visible = false;
        pictureBox6.Visible = false;

        var random = new Random();
        computer = random.Next(1,4);            

        if (computer == 1)
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            label8.Text = "Tie!";                               
    }
```

Comment: `var` doesn't mean what you think it means. It's an implicitly-typed variable. `var random = new Random()` is still of type `Random`.

Comment: `var` is absolutely OK. It's OK in many places, and this style of use here is **totally OK** because there's `= new Random` just an inch farther, so nobody ever can have any problem knowing what the actual type of that `var`. Aside from that, rest of the answer is fine, so please just remove that remark regarding `var`, and the answer will be all good.